# Finding an individual's working speed from group working speed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem, ratio

> Allen can finish a job in $6$ days. If Andrea works with him as they finish the job in $2$ days, how many days will it take Hermione to finish the job alone?

I'm confused as how to build up an equation for this one. Is it built up like $\frac16+\frac12+\frac1x= 1$? Any kind of help will do.

Comment: Can you explain how you set up the equation? The part where Hermione is mentioned seems a little off to me, so are you sure that is how the question is worded?

Comment: I based it on the formula used for work problems. Here it is: (1/a ± 1/b ) t = 1

Comment: I think you meant Andrea instead of Hermione . Please correct it then .

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo from my textbook. I just confirmed it. Also, I have found a way to solve it but thank you anyway :)

Comment: You have gotten the correct value of $x$ by chance. If you try the problem with different numbers, the formula you wrote does not work (such as $24$ and $18$).

Answer (score 2):

(I am assuming you meant Andrea when you said “Hermione”, otherwise this question is unsolvable.)

“Allen can finish the job in $6$ days” is equivalent to “Allen does $\frac16$ of the job in one day”. Using the same logic we can say Andrea and Allen finish $\frac12$ of the job in one day.

The total contribution of Andrea is $\text{how much the 2 people contribute together - how much Allen contributes}=\frac12-\frac16$.

Once you find out how much Andrea contributes in a day, you can find out how long it takes her to finish the job by herself.

Answer (score 0):

In $2$ days Allen has done ${1\over3}$ of the job, hence Andrea has done ${2\over3}$. It follows that Andrea alone would do the full job in $3$ days.